# Correlation length during phase transitions in early Universe

Tags: cosmology, phase-transition, topology, cosmological-inflation, topological-field-theory

During phase transitions of the second kind topological defects may form on the bounds of two areas separated by correlation length. In early Universe during phase transitions correlation length $l_{corr}$ is bounded from above as $l_{corr} \leqslant l_{h}$, where $l_{h}$ corresponds to causal horizon scale. So I expect number of topological defects of order one.

Is such expectation true? Does inflation somehow affect on this statement?